# Cassandra partitioned despite having connectivity and matching schema

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

I have a 3 node cassandra (3.0.15) cluster, where nodes seem to have partitioned. `nodetool status` and `nodetool describecluster` outputs are inconsistent when seen from different nodes. Gossip information (`nodetool gossipinfo`) seems to be up to date on all nodes. No errors in the logs other than read timeouts which seems to be due from the partitioning.

Attempts to resolve this that didn't work:

1. Rolling restart
2. Full cluster restart
3. disable/enable gossip on each node

**Node1 (192.168.2.247):**

```
$ nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
        Name: Test Cluster
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                59ffe9aa-aca7-34b3-8c5e-b736d221b922: [192.168.2.248, 192.168.2.247]

                UNREACHABLE: [192.168.2.249]

$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.2.248  210.23 GB  256          67.7%             f6593c49-6739-4b8c-a8d9-8321915a660d  rack1
DN  192.168.2.249  190.9 GB   256          68.6%             6ac211c2-bab1-4e2b-bc84-18d911e005d0  rack1
UN  192.168.2.247  157.82 GB  256          63.7%             eb462857-cbfb-4e41-8be9-5d241d273b81  rack1
```

**Node2 (192.168.2.248):**

```
$ nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
        Name: Test Cluster
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                59ffe9aa-aca7-34b3-8c5e-b736d221b922: [192.168.2.248, 192.168.2.249, 192.168.2.247]

$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.2.248  210.24 GB  256          67.7%             f6593c49-6739-4b8c-a8d9-8321915a660d  rack1
UN  192.168.2.249  190.9 GB   256          68.6%             6ac211c2-bab1-4e2b-bc84-18d911e005d0  rack1
UN  192.168.2.247  157.82 GB  256          63.7%             eb462857-cbfb-4e41-8be9-5d241d273b81  rack1
```

**Node3 (192.168.2.249):**

```
$ nodetool describecluster
Cluster Information:
        Name: Test Cluster
        Snitch: org.apache.cassandra.locator.DynamicEndpointSnitch
        Partitioner: org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
        Schema versions:
                59ffe9aa-aca7-34b3-8c5e-b736d221b922: [192.168.2.248]

                UNREACHABLE: [192.168.2.249, 192.168.2.247]

$ nodetool status
Datacenter: datacenter1
=======================
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address        Load       Tokens       Owns (effective)  Host ID                               Rack
UN  192.168.2.248  210.24 GB  256          67.7%             f6593c49-6739-4b8c-a8d9-8321915a660d  rack1
UN  192.168.2.249  190.92 GB  256          68.6%             6ac211c2-bab1-4e2b-bc84-18d911e005d0  rack1
UN  192.168.2.247  157.84 GB  256          63.7%             eb462857-cbfb-4e41-8be9-5d241d273b81  rack1
```

Comment: I suspect an issue in the cassandra.yaml file to do with listen addresses / listen_interface you have set, can you include the details of those for each of the 3 nodes.

Comment: `listen_address` and `rpc_address` are set to the corresponding IPs, both being the same for each node. No `listen_interface` configured. seeds are configured with all three IPs.

Comment: Any firewall rules in place? it seems they can't talk to each other, it's very inconsistent what can see each other.

Comment: No firewall rules, and telnet to storage port (7000) works across all node combinations. One thing to note is that there is high compaction on node3 (~8h time to complete). Tried pausing compaction for a while but it didn’t help.

Comment: There is nothing obvious, its a simple 3 node cluster, but something is clearly not right. The 3 cassandra.yaml files is where I would be checking first, but diagnosis of this is well beyond SO.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew. An update on this. Node (server) restart of all the nodes seemed to have made Cassandra happy again. Not sure what to make out of it.